# Можно ли повернуть одну фигуру из массива?

Tags: python, numpy

Допустим у меня есть массив 1000 х 1000 и несколько фигур в нем.

Как повернуть одну фигуру, не весь массив целиком, на 30 градусов?
Возможно криво написал, но надеюсь поймете.

Comment: Пример Вашего кода?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему это невыполнимо / нецелесообразно в Numpy.

Можно попробовать сделать следующее:

- вычленить / вырезать фигуру
- подумать чем заполнить то место где изначально была фигура - в зависимости от сложности заднего фона это может быть очень нетривиальная задача. (Представьте, что надо повернуть маску закрывающую лицо - как восстановить детали лица закрытые маской??)
- наложить вырезанную фигуру на прозрачный фон и создать новое изображение
- повернуть созданное изображение
- наложить повернутое изображение на исходное (с восстановленным фоном), учитывая, что после поворота, части повернутой фигуры могут выходить за границы изначальной картинки